# Как узнать какая запись по счёту

Tags: mysql, sql

есть таблица (упрощено):

```
id  status name     id_task
1   1      Название 2
2   1      Название 1
3   1      Название 3
4   1      Название 6
5   1      Название 4
6   1      Название 5
```

Соответственно всё это получается вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM task ORDER BY id_task
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что бы получить порядковую позицию определённой записи. Ума не приложу как это сделать.

Т.е, допустим, нужно узнать порядковый номер записи с id = 4, ORDER BY всегда `id_task`, если считать вручную, то получится, что эта запись будет шестой. Как это сделать силами mysql?

Версия сервера: MySQL 5.1.73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию ROW_NUMBER() (доступно с версии 8). Если нужно считать порядок не по порядку как записи в запрос, то можно использовать расширенный вариант: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (<partition_definition> <order_definition>).
Если версия MySQL ниже 8, то можно попробовать эмулировать ее как это предлагается [тут](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: Не знал про такую функцию, спасибо, дополнит вопрос, Версия сервера: MySQL 5.1.73

Comment: я дополнил ответ

Comment: Хороший ответ. +1 с моей стороны.